# Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters - Adding example via XML comments

Tags: github, swashbuckle

This link https://github.com/mattfrear/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters#do-not-use-this-filter-unless-you-have-to says to avoid using filters to generate examples as the author wants to deprecate the feature.

He advises using XML comments. In my case I want to generate an example of payload which has a list of items, how can add example for multiple different items in a list using XML comments?

This is what my payload looks like - I would like to generate an example of both serviceType1 and serviceType2 in the list

```
{
    "services" : [
        {
            "type": "serviceType1",
            "serviceNumber": "ABC123",
            "address": "123 sample st"
        },
        {
            "type": "serviceType2",
            "serviceNumber": "ABC123",
            "address": "123 sample st",
            "mobileNumber": "098899898"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I have similar question, for providing examples to objects defined in other packages. I didn't find a way to do it.